# MacOSX terminal which git return error: zsh: bad option: -l

Tags: git, macos, iterm2, iterm

I have noticed some problems lately on my git and I want to uninstall it, when I try to identify the path with:

```
  which git
```

I always get the following error:

```
zsh: bad option: -l
```

any ideas what this error might be indicating?

I have tried on iterm and on default terminal but get always the same error.

Comment: Do you get the same error with `which ls` (or any other standard Unix utility)?

Comment: @Leon yeah I'm getting exact same error: ` which ls     zsh: bad option: -l` . What does this means?

Comment: You didn't bind any command on which ?
Can you check your .bash_profile / .bashrc

Comment: Try running `set -x` and check whether any additional output after calling `which` suggests what the problem is.

Comment: @Zooly, it was an overriding in the zshrc  just erased it and now its working, if you want to include you comment as answer I'll upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` (maybe `.zshrc`) has an alias on **which** command.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was having trouble getting sdkman to work and seeing this:

```
danbitter@Dans-MBP ~ % source "/Users/danbitter/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
find: -type: open: unknown type
/Users/danbitter/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh:83: parse error near `-a'
```

Thanks to [@marc0der & @helpermethod](https://github.com/sdkman/sdkman-cli/issues/806), the issue was in my .zshrc file:

`alias -g f='open -a Finder ./' # f: Opens current directory in MacOS Finder`

This is super weird because disabling that line in the .zshrc file allows sdkman to function in the zsh shell.
But, I can then paste the actual command `open -a Finder ./` in that same zsh shell and it opens a Finder in the working directory? Color me confused ¯\*(ツ)*/¯

edit: I changed it from an `alias -g` to a function `f() {open .;}` and now my .zshrc works happily alongside sdkman :-)